# API to build a custom search engine that searches and displays results in my site

Tags: php, api, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I am looking for a search-engine API, preferably in PHP, that I can use to build a custom search engine that only searches my website.

And whose results I can style with CSS, so I believe that requires the results page to be in my site / on my server.

I would prefer to not use Bing's API.

But, if you have any APIs or solutions to achieve what I am trying to achieve, I would sincerely appreciate it and feel free to share them.

Comment: Although the post is closed, I had the same question recently. And I have posted the solution here: https://www.supportivehands.net/building-a-custom-search-engine-utilizing-google-and-bing-search-results/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), it is dead easy to set up and use because it's just REST. There is also already a very well done php lib for it, [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica).

You'll have to build your own index based on whatever you need. But I can tell you that it is *very* efficient and we implemented it within a day.

Comment: Did you implement ElasticSearch or Elastica ? I am having some trouble getting started with Elastica. Do you know of any demos or examples or even tutorials on how I can build a search-engine using it that accepts input from a html5 form on submission of that form ?

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation on the Elastic Search site, that's what I did it is good enough to get everything done. Elastica itself is pretty self explaining IMHO. As I said it took just a day to get a search implemented without any knowledge about Elastic Search before.

Comment: Documentation on the Elastic Search site? Do you mind linking to it as I couldn't find it. Elastica did seem straight forward, but I was looking for a getting-started guide or tutorial to make sure I did it correctly.

Comment: It's all in the sidebar... http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/ You can also ask for help in #elasticsearch, irc.freenode.net I've got pretty competent support there.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the work documentation. My bad, sorry. Okay, thank you for your help. I'll look at those and ask for help in the irc.freenode.net too if I need it. Thank you.

Comment: I've been able to install and set up elastic search and elastica, but I'm not getting any results. May I see your code without the index and documents being added. Or would you mind taking a look at mine— it only has one document being added. That has the query in it.

Comment: Post your problem with code as public question here on stackoverflow? If you want a private consultant to look at your code you can hire my company or me. I can not share the code because of NDA, this was done for a client project.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. There was a backward slash in the place of a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for `PHP search engine` will have some solutions you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look athe google search api https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/